# Delete file from deployed web app from within the app

Tags: java, tomcat, io, application-server

I have a Java web application that I build as WAR and deploy on Apache Tomcat. Let's say that I have a mechanism built-in my app to determine when it is successfully deployed and running on the server (I'll call it SuccessHandler). Conditionally in the SuccessHandler I need to programmatically delete a file from the project's deployment directory (say `path-to-tomcat/webapps/my-project/file.txt`) how can I do that?

Disclamer: I am able to load/delete files from the resources directories that reside in `path-to-tomcat/webapps/my-project/WEB-INF/` after the deployment + I am able to delete the files using hard-coded absolute path but this is not what I am looking for. I want to be able to delete files no matter where the application is deployed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it reliably. The inside of the application isn't writable in the general case. In particular, the archive may be executed in place and not exploded; even if it isn't, there's nothing keeping the server from restoring the file at every launch. You'll need another way to save your state.

Comment: That seems right and pointed me in another direction that I believe is a good idea - I will try is to extract the conditions to the build tool (Maven in my case) so it packages the WAR with the right files build inside.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would need to delete the file only to write a new one in it's place.

Perhaps overwriting a file is a better approach?

I assume you have the directory where your application is deployed stored as a file, you could call directory.getAbsolutePath() on this and append your "path to file" to that path.

Answer (score 0):

You can store and delete files outside of your webapp folder, for example in `path-to-tomcat/lib/....`